# Enable or disable launch intent-filter activities with one button

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app  with several activities, they all have a launch intent-filter in the manifest so they can show several icons on the launcher, there is a main activity and the rest of them are disabled by default with `android:enabled="false"` here is a part of my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.Activity_1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/secondary_activity"
        android:enabled="false">// HERE I DISABLE THE ACTIVITY
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I found a way to enable or disable the other activities using the following code:

```
public static void enableComponent(Context context, Class<?> componentClass, boolean isEnable) {
   int enableFlag = isEnable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
   context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, componentClass), enableFlag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
private void setupDetailsOverviewRowPresenter() {
  detailsPresenter.setOnActionClickedListener(new OnActionClickedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
        if (action.getId() == ACTION_ENABLE){
                mSelectedApp = (App) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.APP);
                enableComponent(mContext, com.myapp.Activity_1.class, true);
            }
        }else if (action.getId() == ACTION_DISABLED){
                mSelectedApp = (App) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.APP);
                enableComponent(mContext, com.myapp.Activity_1.class, false);
        }
       }
    });
}
```

This works perfectly by enabling or disabling the activity with the `ACTION_ENABLE` or `ACTION_DISABLE` buttons, but that's not good for usability, instead I would like to use just one button to enable or disable the activity.

What I need to know is how to get the status of the activity, so if the activity is `android:enabled="false"` display the button with `ACTION_EANBLE` and if the activity is `android:enabled="true"` display the button with `ACTION_DISABLE`.

Comment: add a boolean indicating on/off status in your class?

Comment: Could you explain me a little more? I am not very good a booleans

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `PackageManager` to determine if a component is enabled or not:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(...);
ActivityInfo info = pm.getActivityInfo(cn, 0);
if (info != null && info.enabled) {
    // Component is enabled
    ...
} else {
    // Component is disabled
    ... 
}
```

Comment: This gives an Unhandled exception: "android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException"

Comment: What are you passing to ``getActivityInfo()`?

Comment: The name of the activity, something like `com.myapp.Activity_1`, what should I put there?

Comment: actually the list of disabled activities are in a subfolder called shortcuts, so I am really passing `com.valecast.myapplication.shortcuts.shortcut_1`

Comment: Please paste exactly how you create the `ComponentName`. You aren't creating it correctly.

Comment: `PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.valecast.myapplication.shortcuts.shortcut_1");
        ActivityInfo info = pm.getActivityInfo(cn, 0);`

Comment: Try `ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getActivity(), "com.valecast.myapplication.shortcuts.shortcut‌​_1");` or `ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getActivity(), com.valecast.myapplication.shortcuts.shortcut‌​_1.class);`

Comment: nope :( it does not work, if may help on something, I am using the `android.support.v17.leanback` library my class is `public class VideoDetailsFragment extends DetailsFragment` not the usual `AppCompat` I don't know if this makes any difference

Comment: the code you gave me doesn't work, it looks very logic, but it doesn't work on my app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129831/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-valerie-castle).

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?